# fluid layout - preserve layout

Tags: html, mobile, css, fluid-layout

I recently created a website: www.hauswoods.com

The site looks fine on a standard screen but on a  mobile device it's terrible. I attempted to adjust the site to be fluid by changing widths to % but then the layout screws up.

If anyone is kind enough to take a look at the site on both a mobile device and standard screen it's clear I have two distinct problems I'm trying to solve:

1) the navigation - what must I do to maintain navigation as on the mobile it appears twice as high and width does not adjust to fit the screen.

2) the content of the html doc is a holder div with two elements: a paragraph and image elements floated to the right. On the mobile there appears to be no padding or margin and it's like the edges are cut - basically the layout really is messed up on a mobile and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Could you tell what is your mobile device? I just checked Dolphin Browser and Opera on Android. On the first one page look quite good(just some minor issues with background, but it's because screen aspect ratio). On second animated gallery script fails to load with causes some mess, but the rest isn't that bad.

Anyway I would recommend separate css for mobile devices.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I was looking at the site on an iphone and on an ipad. I understand that some code will not work on all browsers though, nevertheless, have attempted to use html5 and css3 features that I'm aware will not work on all browsers. I'm also a novice which I suspect is apparent. Yes I'll likely create a separate style sheet for mobile in the near future but it would be nice to have the piece of mind that the site will appear as designed on smaller screens in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

dear doug firr u make a seprate css for this site on mobile but it does not a good technique,u must use html5 fluid template for ur site then u never ever need a seprate design for ur web.u can make just one css and then its compatible with mobile as well as computers and tablets also